# JQM horizontal scroll navbar

Tags: jquery-mobile, scrollview, navbar

i"ve been hunting the docs and can't seem to find a way to make a scrollable horizontal navbar in [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) has anybody accomplished this yet ?

here's what i have for navbar so far

```
<div data-role="header" data-scroll="x">
    <ul>
        <li class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="img/iphoneheader.gif" alt="Penn State Live" /></a></li>
        <li id="link"><a href="#type=colleges">Colleges</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Campuses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Faculty and Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Of Interest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Newswire Subscription</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PSUTXT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm interested to know exactly what you mean by "scrollable horizontal navbar".  Is there an example out there of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @groovetrain like this http://valums.com/files/2009/menu/final.htm but just for a nav so you can swipe left or right to get to more menu items

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I guess this is what you want.

HTML.

```
    <div class="categories">                
            <ul>                    
                <li><span><a href="">ABC</a></span></li>
                <li><span><a href="">DEF</a></span></li>
                <li><span><a href="">GHI</a></span></li>
                <li><span><a href="">JKL</a></span></li>
            </ul>               
        </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){           
    var step = 1;
    var current = 0;
    var maximum = $(".categories ul li").size();
    var visible = 2;
    var speed = 500;
    var liSize = 120;
    var height = 60;    
    var ulSize = liSize * maximum;
    var divSize = liSize * visible; 

    $('.categories').css("width", "auto").css("height", height+"px").css("visibility", "visible").css("overflow", "hidden").css("position", "relative");
    $(".categories ul li").css("list-style","none").css("display","inline");
    $(".categories ul").css("width", ulSize+"px").css("left", -(current * liSize)).css("position", "absolute").css("white-space","nowrap").css("margin","0px").css("padding","5px");

    $(".categories").swipeleft(function(event){
        if(current + step < 0 || current + step > maximum - visible) {return; }
        else {
            current = current + step;
            $('.categories ul').animate({left: -(liSize * current)}, speed, null);
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(".categories").swiperight(function(){
        if(current - step < 0 || current - step > maximum - visible) {return; }
        else {
            current = current - step;
            $('.categories ul').animate({left: -(liSize * current)}, speed, null);
        }
        return false;
    });         
});
```

Comment: Great effort. It doesn't seem to work very smoothly on an iPhone I'm testing it on. It's quite a stop/start scrolling motion.

Answer (score 2):

Also, try out:  http://kryops.de/jqm/tabs/demo

This looks really promising and performance is great on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not what you're looking for but:

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9zuxH/10/

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="jqm-home">
    <ul >
        <li data-role="fieldcontain"> 
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="img/iphoneheader.gif" alt="Penn State Live" /></a></div>
                <div id="link"><a href="#type=colleges">Colleges</a></div>
                <a href="#">Campuses</a>
                <a href="#">Faculty and Staff</a>
                <a href="#">Of Interest</a>
                <a href="#">Photos</a>
                <a href="#">Video</a>
                <a href="#">Newswire Subscription</a>
                <a href="#">PSUTXT</a>
            </fieldset>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Documentation: jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/lists/lists-forms-inset.html

UPDATED the example: http://jsfiddle.net/9zuxH/21/
A little better

Comment: your new example seems to work fine in ff and in safari but not on iphone/ipad safari

Comment: You will need to tweek it as I'm just using the code you provided in the example from your comment. You should be able to do this, Please share your code when you figure out how. Good luck!

Comment: i did find http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll which does what I want but I can't click on the links in it which is a problem

Comment: For me, this fiddle works better on mobile. I'm using an iPad and performance is way better than the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is after ypur lst comment, so I'll be addressing the need to scroll the navbar with a finger.

You pointed to an implementation that has problems. There are others.
I have used this once:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQclickNScroll
for a desktop touchscreen. (not sure how it behaves on mobile)
It worked with a hrefs and it has an option `allowHiliting:true` that turns off preventing other events passing through

And there's this:
http://digitalillusion.altervista.org/wordpress/pages/dragscroller/viewport-test.html

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this while researching the same issue. Haven't tried it yet but it looks pretty handy

http://darsa.in/sly/