# jquery mobile navbar overflow

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am building a jQuery Mobile application, and on its header I have a navbar widget set up. Structure is like a regular jQM navbar (CSS structure is jQM's default):

```
<nav data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">...</a></li>
        <li><a href="">...</a></li>
        <li><a href="">...</a></li>
        <li><a href="">...</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want the navbar to have fixed width buttons, and horizontal overflow, so I can set up a horizontal scroll navbar through a jQuery script like the one found here: [JQM horizontal scroll navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738446/jqm-horizontal-scroll-navbar).

The problem is, the framework always creates a new line when it has no more room for buttons: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNrk5.png, yet my intended behavior is something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPbm4.jpg.

I've tried tinkering with the CSS structure, setting overflow:hidden, white-space, fixed height navbar, etc, but to no success so far.

Am I missing something here?