# jQuery Mobile custom draggable Navbar

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to make a navbar in footer with more than 5 items, something like 
[DailyMailOnline App for android](https://lh3.ggpht.com/BWUUr-mJ06S8uVvcFS2Dv6cfwIsPtuV8y6MZyHesY1kLaSCogc0UmHggDoKfqS7HBdA)

The 'quest' for plugin was pure defeat.

Anything to recommend (plugin, fiddle, ...) or an idea how to implement this kind of navbar ?

Comment: someone has it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738446/jqm-horizontal-scroll-navbar Although I would prefer that it start scrolling with the drag and not after the drag. but this is a good start

Comment: refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738446/jqm-horizontal-scroll-navbar