# Jquery Mobile Footer NavBar Horizontal Scroll

Tags: jquery-mobile, footer, horizontal-scrolling, navbar

I'm using the "navbar" data-role for a div inside JQuery Mobile's footer definition. When I add more than 5 items it divides the menu items into two columns. This is default behaviour according to the JQM documentation. I'd like the icons to be scrollable by swiping left or right inside the footer area.

```
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed" id="divFooter">
            <div data-role="navbar" id="divNavBar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" id="icPortfolio" data-icon="custom">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" id="icStatus" data-icon="custom">Status</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For reference, I looked at this potential solution: [JQM horizontal scroll navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738446/jqm-horizontal-scroll-navbar). It however turns the menu icons into HTML links and works inside the header data-role.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  Combining `horizontal` and `scroll` doesn't mean the same thing as the tag `horizontal-scrolling`.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the following on your parent div (on your footer div)

```
overflow: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
```

The nowarp makes the div contents not overflow to the next line and the overflow auto makes it scrollable in whichever direction it will not fit which in this case is horizontal since we turned off word wrap

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve this with HTML/CSS only:

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <nav role='navigation'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <a href="#" class="nav-toggle">Menu</a>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  overflow-x: scroll; /* 1 */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* 2 */
}

ul {
  text-align: justify; /* 3 */
  width: 30em; /* 4 */
}


ul:after { /* 5 */
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: inline-block; /* 6 */
}
```

Comments:

1. Setting auto will work on some devices, but set this to scroll just
   to be sure.
2. This the magic property that enables the native feel
   scrolling.
3. Setting this to justify creates equally spaced li's which
   takes the headache of working out margins.
4. You must set the width to
   a value larger than the sum of all the li's width.
5. This is `text-align: justify`'s version of a clearfix.
6. This must also be set for the equal spacing to work.

Should work on the following devices:

- **iOS 5+**
- **Android 3.0**
- Blackberry 6+ (didn't check personally)
- **Windows Phone** (IE10) supports momentum scrolling natively

Taken from here: http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/23/scroll-overflow-menu/